# Terminology for Combining (Intersecting?) Partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, set-partition

What's the term for making a new partition from two existing partitions of a space? For example, if you have a partition $X = \{A, B\}$ and $Y = \{C, D\}$, and you form the partition $\{AC, AD, BC, BD\}$, what do you call it? (Example: on the interval $[0, 4]$, $X = \{[0, 2), [2, 3]\}$ and $Y = \{[0, 1), [1, 3]\}$, so the new partition is $\{[0, 1), [1, 2), [2, 3]\}$.)

For example, do you call it "the partition formed through *intersecting* $X$ and $Y$"? Or "the partition formed through *crossing* $X$ and $Y$"?

Thank you!

Comment: So, you are looking for a name and a symbol commonly used for an operation, what I'll type as $\Cap$, defined as $X\Cap Y = \{x\cap y~:~x\in X,~y\in Y\}$, maybe removing the empty set after.  I'm sorry to say I don't know of one.  If I needed such a thing, I would define it at the time of using it.

Comment: Alternately worded, perhaps you are looking for a [partition refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_refinement) $R$, such that $R$ is the "smallest" partition such that it is a refinement both of $X$ and of $Y$.

Comment: As "$X$ refines $Y$" forms a lattice on the collection of all partitions of the base set, you could call the partition you are after the "meet" or "join" of partitions $X$ and $Y$. depending on whether you consider "refines" to be a $\le$ or $\ge$ relation.